# Google Earth Engine Export CSV MODIS Pixel Data for Multiple Polygons within a Rectangle

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, modis

Having watched GEE tutorials, pieced together code from several StackExchange questions and received help from Kuik and Jobbo90 I managed to write a code for a MODIS/006/MOD11A1 surface temperature time series; https://code.earthengine.google.com/e66a97bf90ceff11d81331be86e0f969.

I would now like to adapt the code so that the CSV output file includes three new columns; 
1) Pixel longitude 
2) Pixel latitude 
3) Pixel area name (either a Tokyo district name or if not within a district and within the rectangle then labelled vicinity).

Having watched the GEE Tables and Vectors tutorial; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLE-apehUCk and sought help from StackExchange questions such as; [Extract Pixel Values for Multiple Polygons and Images](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294595/extract-pixel-values-for-multiple-polygons-and-images?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Extracting pixel values by points and converting to table in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265392/extracting-pixel-values-by-points-and-converting-to-table-in-google-earth-engine/265618#265618) I attempted to adjust the code but have failed to do so.

In the Tables and Vectors tutorial Nick Clinton states "here`s one way" to make a table which suggests that there are multiple ways to formulate a table and perhaps this explains why I am struggling to adjust my code with information from different sources.

I predict that I need to adjust something in the following section of my code from the first link but I can`t figure out how/where;

```
function spacedPoints(fc, proj) {
  var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(proj);
  var coords = latlon.select(['longitude', 'latitude'])
                 .reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
                                geometry: fc.geometry(1).buffer(proj.nominalScale().toInt()),
                                scale: proj.nominalScale().toInt()
  });
  var point_list = ee.List(coords.get('longitude')).zip(ee.List(coords.get('latitude')));
  print(point_list);
  var list = ee.List([0]);
  var feats = ee.FeatureCollection(point_list.map(function(point){
    var ind = point_list.indexOf(point);
    var feat = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(point_list.get(ind)), {'ID': ind});
    return list.add(feat);
  }).flatten().removeAll([0]));
  return feats.filterBounds(fc.geometry(1));
}
```

How can I adjust the above code so that three new columns; 1) Pixel longitude 
2) Pixel latitude 
3) Pixel area name are added to the exported CSV file?

Comment: To make this possible, please transform all geometries to a featurecollection with each feature a property named to the state it belongs to, like this: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/694c23f9c87aa3f572e00455208b84da)

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment above points out, you will need to turn your geometries into a ee.FeatureCollection, with their name as a property. Then you can map over your temperatures, extract the name from intersecting region, and the latitude/longitude from the geometry. Something like this:

```
var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(Adachi, {name: 'Adachi'}),
  ee.Feature(Katsushika, {name: 'Katsushika'}),
  ee.Feature(Edogawa, {name: 'Edogawa'}),
  ee.Feature(Arakawa, {name: 'Arakawa'}),
  ee.Feature(Sumida, {name: 'Sumida'}),
  ee.Feature(Taito, {name: 'Taito'}),
  ee.Feature(Kita, {name: 'Kita'}),
  ee.Feature(Bunkyo, {name: 'Bunkyo'}),
  ee.Feature(Toshima, {name: 'Toshima'}),
  ee.Feature(Itabashi, {name: 'Itabashi'}),
  ee.Feature(Nerima, {name: 'Nerima'}),
  ee.Feature(Koto, {name: 'Koto'}),
  ee.Feature(Chuo, {name: 'Chuo'}),
  ee.Feature(Chiyoda, {name: 'Chiyoda'}),
  ee.Feature(Minato, {name: 'Minato'}),  
  ee.Feature(Shinagawa, {name: 'Shinagawa'}),  
  ee.Feature(Meguro, {name: 'Meguro'}),
  ee.Feature(Setagaya, {name: 'Setagaya'}),
  ee.Feature(Shibuya, {name: 'Shibuya'})
])
// Add geometry for part of AOI not in one of the regions
var vicinity = fc.geometry().difference(regions.geometry(), 30) 
regions = regions.merge(ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(vicinity, {name: 'Vicinity'})]))

// calculate the temperature over the time span at every point in the AOI
var temperatures = multiband
  .reduceRegions({
    collection: points, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    scale: 1000
  })
  .map(function (feature) {
    var geometry = feature.geometry()
    var name = regions
      .filterBounds(geometry)
      .first()
      .get('name')
    var coords = geometry.centroid().coordinates()
    var additionalData = ee.Feature(null, {
      name: name, 
      longitude: coords.get(0), 
      latitude: coords.get(1)
    })
    return feature.copyProperties(additionalData)
  })
print('feature collection of temperatures', temperatures);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: temperatures,
  description: '2018August', 
  fileNamePrefix: '2018August', 
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4d8097ed300142e689f38b2475681a54

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel, your code has been a great help.